# Vue equivalent to express [GET, POST]

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Here is my piece of code I've written

```
export let postChapter = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    var chapterInfoModel = mongoose.model(`${req.params.novelId}`, RiChapterScheme);

    var array = {
        title: req.body.chapterTitle,
        content: req.body.chapterContent
    };

    let newChapterInfo = new chapterInfoModel(array);

    newChapterInfo.save((err, book) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({ error: err, affected: book });
        } else if (!err) {
            res.redirect('/novels/' + req.params.novelId);
        }
    });
};
```

The above code is my controller. This is the piece that I don't know how to convert into my vue setup

since my express router is set up as so

```
this.router.post('/novels/:novelId', novelController.postNovel);
```

and here is my vue router

**router.ts**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    }
  ]
})
```

my vue-cli plugins are as follows

- vue-router
- vuex

**Home.Vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img id='mainLogo' src='@/assets/logo.jpg'>
        <form method="POST"></form>
            <button type="submit"></button>
    </div>
</template>
```

How would I implement this?

```
var chapterInfoModel = mongoose.model(`${req.params.novelId}`, RiChapterScheme);
let newChapterInfo = new chapterInfoModel(array);

newChapterInfo.save((err, book) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send({ error: err, affected: book });
    } else if (!err) {
        res.redirect('/novels/' + req.params.novelId);
    }
});
```

into my vue router or does this go into my Home.vue?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve.  You want to post a book object to your express server and save it within a mongoose Data base?

Comment: Ahh no I want to I want to post from my cue server to my mongodb :/ since it works differently in express since I could just do the .post to the router but not in view since I’m confused as to how would I post from inside vue when I press my button to submit

Comment: Ahh ok. Its not possible to do that directly because Vue is a client-side framework so it can't communicate directly with a database. Vue can only communicate via HTTP therefore you would need to send a Post HTTP request to your express server. Your express server can then send commands directly to your mongoDB and save data to it, make sense?

Comment: @MJ_Wales ahhh thanks for clearing up my misunderstandings of vue

Comment: Thanks! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers: Its not possible to directly access a database using Vue because it is a client-side framework. Vue can only communicate via HTTP therefore you would need to send a Post HTTP request to your a backend server (express in this case). The backend server would handle the request and then save the data to your database.

[Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) is a very useful package for easily writing HTTP requests. Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249384/read-data-from-a-mongodb-database-using-vuejs) might be helpful as it describes all the steps you need to make.